# how to compute the average time in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file that has time represented in a format I'm not familiar with:

[image]

I am trying to compute the average time in all of those rows (efforts shown below).
Any sort of feedback will be appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas as np
from datetime import datetime


flyer = pd.read_csv("./myfile.csv",parse_dates = ['timestamp'])

flyer.dropna(axis=0, how='any', thresh=None, subset=None, inplace=True)

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 20)

flyer['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(flyer['timestamp'], 
infer_datetime_format=True)
p = flyer.loc[:,'timestamp'].mean()


print(flyer['timestamp'].mean())
```

Comment: That's called the ISO format. You should look into the datetime and dateutil packages of Python. Those are good for parsing timestamps.

Comment: Thanks Ill check it out

Comment: Try `pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True).mean()`.

Comment: Sorry What does the code mean. I just started panda this morning. I know that Pd means the panda module and that df is the variable of the csv

Comment: df is your data where timestamp is the column.

Comment: When I try to use this code I get this error: TypeError: cannot perform mean with type datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)]

Comment: @aymanalmuti I edited my answer with a possible mean solution. It's a bit confusing, but calculating the mean is a bit tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The above is correct, but if you're new it might not be as clear what 0x is feeding you.

```
import pandas as pd

# turn your csv into a pandas dataframe
df = pd.read_csv('your/file/location.csv')
```

The timestamp column might be interpreted as a bunch of strings, you won't be able to do the math you want on strings.

```
# this forces the column's data into timestamp variables
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], infer_datetime_format=True)

# now for your answer, get the average of the timestamp column
print(df['timestamp'].mean())
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time to answer my question. But there is one problem and that it says that it cannot do mean with datetime64 thank you in advance any answer

Answer (score 0):

When you read the csv with pandas, add `parse_dates = ['timestamp']` to the `pd.read_csv()` function call and it will read in that column correctly. The T in the timestamp field is a common way to separate the date and the time.

The -4:00 indicates time zone information, which in this case means -4:00 hours in comparison to UTC time.

As for calculating the mean time, that can get a bit tricky, but here's one solution for after you've imported the csv.

```
from datetime import datetime

pd.to_datetime(datetime.fromtimestamp(pd.to_timedelta(df['timestamp'].mean().total_seconds())))
```

This is converting the field to a datetime object in order to calculate the mean, then getting the total seconds (EPOCH time) and using that to convert back into a pandas datetime series.

Comment: Alright got that down in my code and now the date looks more familiar thank you. Just got one question what does -04:00 mean

Comment: @aymanalmuti I edited the answer to reflect what the -4:00 means; it's time stamp information.

Comment: Hey thank you for replying and taking time out of your day to answer my question. Sadly i'm getting the same error as every time I try to do the mean. its the I cant do mean with datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(-240)]